# Integral of $J_1\left(Ae^{-\lambda t}-Ae^{-\lambda s}\right)e^{-\epsilon(t-s)}$ with respect to $s$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

Consider the integral

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^t\left(\frac{Ae^{-\lambda t}-Ae^{-\lambda s}}{2}\right)^{2m+1}e^{-\epsilon(t-s)}ds,\tag{1}$$

for constants $A,\lambda,\epsilon,t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

The intention of evaluating $\mathcal{I}$, is to find

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S&=\int_0^tJ_1\left(Ae^{-\lambda t}-Ae^{-\lambda s}\right)e^{-\epsilon(t-s)}ds,
\\&=\int_0^t\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{
(-1)^m}{m!(m+1)!}\left(\frac{Ae^{-\lambda t}-Ae^{-\lambda s}}{2}\right)^{2m+1}e^{-\epsilon(t-s)}ds,\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{
(-1)^m}{m!(m+1)!}\mathcal{I}_m
\end{split}\end{equation}

where $J_1$ denotes the first order Bessel function of first kind. Does a closed form exist for $S$ (or Taylor series)? Could an asymptotic bound simplify things?

**Edit:**

According to [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28a-A+exp%28-lambda+s%29%29%5E%282*m%2B1%29+exp%28-epsilon*%28t-s%29%29), we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{I}=\frac{(A-Ae^{-\lambda t})^2 (Ae^{-\lambda t}-A)^{2m} 2^{-2m-1}e^{-\epsilon t}\cdot{}_2F_1\left(1,\frac{\epsilon+\lambda}{\lambda};\frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}-2m,e^{-\lambda t}\right)}{A\left(\epsilon-\lambda(2m+1)\right)}.
\end{equation}

From this, is it possible to prove that
$2\mathcal{S}\sim A\lambda^2\kappa e^{-\lambda t}-A\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$, for some $\kappa$? The sum of the non-hypergeomtric terms of $\mathcal{I}$ is given [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%282%5E%28-2*m-1%29*%28b%29%5E%282*m%29%29%2F%28A*%28epsilon-lambda*%282*m%2B1%29%29%29+from+m%3D0+to+x) or [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5Em*%282%5E%28-2*m-1%29*%28b%29%5E%282*m%29%29%2F%28%28A-z*2*m%29*m%21%28m%2B1%29%21%29+from+m%3D0+to+x), which may help after using Abel summation.

Comment: I think the best that can be done with trig functions is using $Ae^{-\lambda t}=A+\frac{2A}{\coth\left(-\frac{t\gamma}{2}\right)-1}$. Euler's identity would also give us a period of $-2i\pi/\lambda$ but I am integrating over the reals.

Comment: Notice that any function of $A,\lambda,t,\epsilon$ can be ignored, so your [closed form is this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28a%2Bb+exp%28-l+s%29%29%5E%282m%2B1%29+exp%28-e*%28t-s%29%29). If you know:$$\int (a+b e^{-\lambda s})^k e^{\epsilon (s-t)}ds$$, then you can integrate using the link as a guide.

Comment: Since I need to sum $\mathcal{I}$ from $m=0$ to $\infty$ (which almost always converges), I was hoping for a 'nicer' solution. Regardless, I would be interested in how such a closed form could be derived. Would an approximation for $\mathcal{I}_m$ to find $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{I}_m$ help?

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Let $x_t\sim Ae^{-\lambda t}+C$. Is $\kappa\ddot{x}+\dot{x}\sim 2\int_0^t J_1(x_t-x_s)e^{-t(t-s)}ds$ such that $J_a$ is the Bessel function of first kind of order $a$ and $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equivalence? A power series for the RHS produces the summation (and integral) in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131205/discussion-between-tyma-gaidash-and-unowen).

Comment: Also note from [this Incomplete Beta function identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0122.01) that: $$\,_2F_1(1,b,c,z)=(c-1)z^{(1-c)}(1-z)^{c-b+1}\text B_z(c-1,b-c+1)$$

Comment: There is probably a closed form using the [Kampé de Feriét](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235393601_On_a_reduction_formula_for_the_Kampe_de_Feriet_function) function which is also on [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/KampedeFerietFunction.html). It is general hypergeometric function, but we can try and reduce it. Would such a solution be of interest?